# Angular LoadChildren string format deprecated but function format results in error

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-router

Angular 8 (due out any day now) deprecates using the string format for routing LoadChildren as per:
   `type LoadChildren = LoadChildrenCallback | DeprecatedLoadChildren;` from https://next.angular.io/api/router/LoadChildren

Everything is fine in DEV with JIT, but lazy-loading modules in --prod with AOT throws the following error when trying to route to that module:

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded`

I can continue to use the string format and ignore the deprecation warning for now, but it would be nice to get around the deprecation warning as well as have functioning code.

Working string method:

```
{
   path: 'admin',
   loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
},
```

Failing function method:

```
{
   path: 'admin', 
   loadChildren: ():Promise<typeof AdminModule> =>
       import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule)
},
```

I've had this problem with the last several betas and rc's.

Has anyone else found a work-around for this yet?

Comment: Check this:https://blog.angularindepth.com/automatically-upgrade-lazy-loaded-angular-modules-for-ivy-e760872e6084

Comment: Good blog post; thanks for the reference. From that post it sounds as if there is no alternative but to live with the deprecation warning until it's practical to switch to Ivy, which may be several months. I tried Ivy a month or so ago and it was definitely going to slow down development iterations, so in my opinion it wasn't worth turning on yet.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this?

```
[{
  path: 'lazy',
  loadChildren: () => import('./lazy-route/lazy.module').then(mod => mod.LazyModule),
}];
```

The link is for a more recent version of Angular but it may help by giving some idea.
https://angular.io/api/router/LoadChildrenCallback

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4192). It looks like the new [IVY renderer could provide a solution](https://blog.angularindepth.com/automatically-upgrade-lazy-loaded-angular-modules-for-ivy-e760872e6084).